# How to Sign Android App to avoid App not installed from Play Store error?

Tags: gradle, proguard, android-signing

I'm trying to release new update to my users on play store, but whenever I roll out the release all users complaint me about app is not updating or not installing after downloading update from play store.

How do I configure my gradle / manifest / or build settings such that users will successfully install the new update without needing to uninstall the existing apk from the device?

Please correct me if my settings are configured incorrectly.

**build.gradle(app)**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 11
        versionName "2.2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    bundle{
        language{
            enableSplit=false
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(project)**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.Firebase** { 

      *;
    }
```

I'm not able to understand which part of the mentioned code having issues with. Sometimes my build takes so much time during running app for testing on device. I new in this signing process. I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can u add screenshot of the error

Comment: Typically for any app created in the playstore later than August 2021 the AAB format is mandatory. Ie you sign your AAB with a "upload key" and the playstore signs the app with the final "distribution key" (this one is either created by the playstore or uploaded once by yourself) So I don't see, how you are even capable of uploading a build signed with a key different from your "upload key". And once you uploaded it, the playstore will use the correct "distribution key" to sign it ...

Comment: @derpirscher how do i correct this issue. any steps to check?

Comment: As I already said: I'm not even sure how you managed to get into this situation, so without some more information (for instance the exact error message)  I'm not able to help you. The only thing that jumps into my eyes is, that your are always using the very same `signingConfigs.debug` for all of your build types ... I would expect this to be different for builds you use for local debugging and builds you are uploading to the playstore ...

Comment: One thing I can imagine is the following: You distributed the APK signed with some key (maybe your debug key) to some users not via playstore but for instance made it available for download from your own website (or any other canal) for testing purposes. Now when they try to update your app via playstore, the get a key-mismatch error because the playstore re-signs the app before distribution. Unfortunately the only way to resolve that is to uninstall the app on the affected devices and reinstall it from the playstore. But any data that isn't stored in a backend will be lost